# What is the security vulnerability with response "expect: 100-continue"

Tags: penetration-testing

I was testing web application from security point. I observed the response containing the 'expect: 100-continue' header. I tried to check if the web application should support the mentioned header in response from vulnerability point of view. but could not get any concluding answer with reasoning why it should / should not support the header. 
Any pointer will help.

thanks

Answer (score -1):

The "Expect: 100-continue" header is used by clients to signal to the server that they intend to send a large request body ,for example file upload, and want to ensure that the server is willing to accept the data before proceeding with the full request.
It helps prevent wasting bandwidth and server resources in cases where the server cannot or should not accept the request, potentially due to size limitations or other conditions.
The server can respond with a "100 Continue" status if it is ready to receive the request body or with an error response if it is not.

Web applications should generally support the "Expect: 100-continue" header if they expect to receive large request bodies and want to improve efficiency in handling such requests.
The header itself  is not a security vulnerability as it's a part of standard HTTP communication. But here's an example usage of the header and the reason why they stopped using it, as it might give you and idea of potential issues the header may cause; https://support.airship.com/hc/en-us/articles/213492003--Expect-100-Continue-Issues-and-Risks

Hope this helps.